# UIview animation misbehaves when image of an unrelated button is changed

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewanimationtransition

On my viewcontroller, I have a button to enable/disable audio using the following action:

```
func audioControl() {
    playMusic = playMusic ? false : true // toggle
    if (playMusic) {
        startMusic()
        audioBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "musicOn"),for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        stopMusic()
        audioBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "musicOff"),for: .normal)
    }
}
```

The button toggles its image, as expected.

There is also an unrelated UIImageView object on the same VC which is being translated as follows:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, delay: 0.0, options: [ .curveLinear, .repeat ], animations: {
    self.movingImg.center = CGPoint(x: screenSize.minX, y: screenSize.maxY)
})
```

This simple animation works fine by itself. However, as soon as the button is tapped, the movingImg object goes outside the boundary of screen and it is no longer visible.

I am not sure why a change of image on a button causes another object animation to misbehave. Any thoughts? I am using Swift 3.

Thank you.

Comment: When press the button, try to see if anything relative layout was changed due to the the ```center``` values is changed.

Comment: Thanks William. From my checks, I am unable to see any direct dependency of layout to the center property of movingImg.

Comment: Also check if you button connected to different ```IBAction```s. If still can't make it, could you provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

After reading through discussions in a number of SO threads, I found that with the image change (along with any other layout changes), the viewcontroller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` gets called. As such, the followings are two things I did to resolve this issue:

1. Within the `audioControl()` method, I removed the animation of movingImg (i.e. `movingImg.layer.removeAllAnimations()`) before updating the button image.
2. I added `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to my viewcontroller and started the animation of movingImg there.

Hopefully, this approach helps others too.